# $.getJSON output html with object that have value loop

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, getjson

I need some help with JSON as I'm not familiar with the best way to accomplish my task:

Here is the json I fetch via URL:

```
[

{"ID":1,"ProgramID":100,"Name":"Class 1","Cost":100},
{"ID":2,"ProgramID":100,"Name":"Class 2","Cost":200},
{"ID":3,"ProgramID":100,"Name":"Class 3","Cost":150},
{"ID":4,"ProgramID":100,"Name":"Class 4","Cost":125},
{"ID":5,"ProgramID":100,"Name":"Class 5","Cost":50},
{"ID":6,"ProgramID":100,"Name":"Class 6","Cost":75},
{"ID":7,"ProgramID":100,"Name":"Class 7","Cost":100},

{"ID":8,"ProgramID":101,"Name":"Class 1","Cost":110},
{"ID":9,"ProgramID":101,"Name":"Class 2","Cost":205},
{"ID":10,"ProgramID":101,"Name":"Class 3","Cost":115},
{"ID":11,"ProgramID":101,"Name":"Class 4","Cost":150},
{"ID":12,"ProgramID":101,"Name":"Class 5","Cost":160},
{"ID":13,"ProgramID":101,"Name":"Class 6","Cost":180},
{"ID":14,"ProgramID":101,"Name":"Class 7","Cost":190}

]
```

I need help creating a function that fetches the data in a loop based on ProgramID.

I'm trying to output the HTML in a loop:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    Class 1
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    $100.00
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    Class 2
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    $200.00
  </div>
</div>
```

etc...

```
function getData(programid) {
  $.getJSON("URL", { ProgramID: +programid}, function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(key, value){
         ??
      });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your `getData` function works but here is a snippet which takes your provided data and extracts only `ProgramID` 101 to place it in a div:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var data = [

{"ID":1,"ProgramID":100,"Name":"Class 1","Cost":100},
{"ID":2,"ProgramID":100,"Name":"Class 2","Cost":200},
{"ID":3,"ProgramID":100,"Name":"Class 3","Cost":150},
{"ID":4,"ProgramID":100,"Name":"Class 4","Cost":125},
{"ID":5,"ProgramID":100,"Name":"Class 5","Cost":50},
{"ID":6,"ProgramID":100,"Name":"Class 6","Cost":75},
{"ID":7,"ProgramID":100,"Name":"Class 7","Cost":100},

{"ID":8,"ProgramID":101,"Name":"Class 1","Cost":110},
{"ID":9,"ProgramID":101,"Name":"Class 2","Cost":205},
{"ID":10,"ProgramID":101,"Name":"Class 3","Cost":115},
{"ID":11,"ProgramID":101,"Name":"Class 4","Cost":150},
{"ID":12,"ProgramID":101,"Name":"Class 5","Cost":160},
{"ID":13,"ProgramID":101,"Name":"Class 6","Cost":180},
{"ID":14,"ProgramID":101,"Name":"Class 7","Cost":190}

];

function getRow(pID) {
  var myD = [];
  
  // Extract data from global variable
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].ProgramID == pID) {
      myD.push(data[i]);
    }
  }
  
  // Container for created rows
  var $result = $('<div />');

 // Iterate extracted data
  for (var i = 0; i < myD.length; i++) {
   // Create new row
    var $row = $('<div class="row"></div>');
    
    // Column 1
    var $col1 = $('<div class="col-xs-6" />');
    $col1.text(myD[i].Name);
    
    // Column 2
    var $col2 = $('<div class="col-xs-6" />');
    $col2.text(myD[i].Cost);
    
    // Append columns
    $row.append($col1);
    $row.append($col2);
    
    // Append row
    $result.append($row);
  }
  
  // Dummy for output
  $('#output').append($result);

  return $result;
}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="getRow(101);" value="click"></input>
<div id="output">

</div>
```

UPDATE:
Your comment suggest that you're already request a filtered datasource. So your function could look like this:

```
function getData(programid) {
  $.getJSON("URL", { ProgramID: programid}, function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(key, value){
         if (data != null) {
         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            // Create new row
             var $row = $('<div class="row"></div>');

             // Column 1
             var $col1 = $('<div class="col-xs-6" />');
             $col1.text(data[i].Name);

             // Column 2
             var $col2 = $('<div class="col-xs-6" />');
             $col2.text(data[i].Cost);

             // Append columns
             $row.append($col1);
             $row.append($col2);

             // Append row
             $result.append($row);
           }

           // Dummy for output
           $('#output').append($result);
         }
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: That's the part I need help with, I don't know how to setup the $.getJSON with URL that fetches what I pasted above. How do I combine the two?

Comment: That looks like the direction I am going, I get error myD isn't defined.

Comment: Sorry, my bad: just replace `myD` with `data`

Comment: You're welcome. Do not hesitate to mark the answer as solution if you don't mind ;-)